# Did chrome in windows 8.1 stop supporting some fonts?

Tags: css, google-chrome, windows-8.1

It seems like chrome stopped support some fonts, but I have only seen this in windows 8.1 Pro. It does only affect google chrome, not other browsers.

Why?

The fonts I talk about are:

- Calibri
- Century Gothic
- Georgia

The version of chrome I am testing this on is: `38.0.2125.104 m`

Comment: Supporting...no, but they did change their font-rendering process I believe. If the fonts are installed they should still display...but they may not render exactly the same as before.

Comment: Calibri renders as arial, it seems

Comment: Can't comment without code or a demo!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c87wLucq/3/ will render as times in chrome in windows 8.1, not in windows 7, where it correctly will render as calibri.

Comment: Why have people voted to close this question?

Comment: My guess is that the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421305

Comment: Make it an answer, please, also, what did you search on?

Comment: I just googled "Chrome not supporting Calibri" ...it's not really an answer as such but I can if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Chrome on Win 8.1

[**Google Code Link**](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421305)